# Adding HTML to string within double quotation marks

Tags: php, regex

I have managed to get this RegExp for matching anything within double quotes:

```
"([^"]|\\")*"
```

Which matches

"**For my part I know nothing with any certainty, but the sight of the stars makes me dream**." - Vincent Van Gogh

What I need to do, using PHP is apply HTML to the match, so the above string would become...

```
<i class="quote">"For my part I know nothing with any certainty, but the sight of the stars makes me dream."</i> - Vincent Van Gogh
```

I've tried with preg_replace but can't get it working how I need it to.

Thanks

Comment: Change your regex to `("[^"]++")`

Comment: Or `(?<!\\)".*?(?<!\\)"` if you need escaping support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
 $str = preg_replace('/("([^"]|\\")*")/', "<i class='quote'>$1</i>", $str);
```

Comment: Oh my, like Thompson and Ritchie :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
echo preg_replace('#"([^"]++)*"#', '<i class="quote">"\1"</i>', 'foo bar "fuz" "buz"')
```

I think the missing part you were looking for was the backreference, \1. It represents whatever is in the first paranthesis in your pattern. If you have more than one paranthesis, \2, \3 etc. represent those.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at preg_match, return a match with your regexp and place it or use a concatenation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

You could use preg_replace but it would seem to be more convoluted for your intent.